# Cookies are not set in Safari until page refresh

Tags: javascript, cookies, safari, js-cookie

If I go to the JS console in Safari and write

```
document.cookie = 'cookie1=test; expires=Sun, 1 Jan 2023 00:00:00 UTC; path=/'
```

the cookie won't be visible under the `Storage` tab until I refresh the page. This behaviour seems to be Safari specific and my page has issues because of it.

Has anybody encountered similar issue? I'm using `js-cookie` library to set cookies `v.3.0.1`.

Comment: Hasn't safari storage tab always worked this way?

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze I think it has. Working with Cookies on Safari is a real pain in the ass. If I remember correctly Safari on iOS also clears cookies when you close the browser completely while Android does not do that.

Comment: Have you guys managed to get around it somehow?

Comment: I actually haven't i just remembered because of websql and it wasn't a problem to hit refresh

Comment: Does anyone have a link to more info on this?